# How to loop a handler.postdelayed only twice

Tags: java, android, loops, handler

I'm using a handler.postdelayed to loop a sound with a delay that can be changed by the user. But I want the sound to play only twice, and then stop. Here's what I have so far, it loops indefinitely:

```
eightHandler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    soundpool.play(drum, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0);
                    eightRunnable = this;
                    handler.postDelayed(eightRunnable, delay);
                }
            }, delay/2);
```

Answer (score 1):

You may do it like this.

```
int i = 0;
eightHandler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    soundpool.play(drum, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0);
                    eightRunnable = this;
                    if(i < 2){
                        handler.postDelayed(eightRunnable, delay);
                    }
                    i++;
                }
            }, delay/2);
```